# Is it possible that an Ethereum Address starts with 0x0

Tags: addresses

Is it possible that an Ethereum Address starts with a 0 on the first place after the hex prefix?

For example:
`0x0c01a1da70b4109be8789af5fd678183145dbe55`

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: It's not only possible, it is true by the definition of an Ethereum Address, which yields the set of all hexadecimal strings of 40 characters (except for the string which is all zeros).

Comment: So technically speaking, you can have as many leading zeros as you want, up to 39 of them. You might have a hard time finding the private key of each one of them, nevertheless, they will all be valid Ethereum addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Here

https://vanity-eth.tk/

YOu can choose the prefix or suffix and they are called vanity addresses

A vanity address is an address which part of it is chosen by yourself, making it look less random.
Examples: 0xc0ffee254729296a45a3885639AC7E10F9d54979, or 0x999999cf1046e68e36E1aA2E0E07105eDDD1f08E